# How to set up a sqlite database from complicated xml?

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am building an Android app which will use a sqlite database that I create using xml data.

I have done this before with simpler xml documents and the approach for this one has me a little stumped.

The app is a verb conjugation app, and here is an example of one of the verbs:

```
    <word>
        <key>aparcar</key>
        <definition>to deposit (arms); to park</definition>
        <conjugation>

<tense type="Infinitivo">aparcar</tense>
<tense type="Participio">aparcado</tense>
<tense type="Gerundio">aparcando</tense>
<tense type="Presente">
    <person type="first_person">aparco</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcas</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparca</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcamos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcáis</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcan</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Imperfecto">
    <person type="first_person">aparcaba</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcabas</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcaba</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcábamos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcabais</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcaban</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Pretérito">
    <person type="first_person">aparqué</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcaste</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcó</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcamos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcasteis</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcaron</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Futuro">
    <person type="first_person">aparcaré</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcarás</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcará</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcaremos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcaréis</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcarán</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Subjunctivo">
    <person type="first_person">aparque</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparques</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparque</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparquemos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparquéis</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparquen</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Subjunctivo_Pretérito">
    <person type="first_person">aparcara</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcaras</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcara</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcáramos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcarais</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcaran</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Subjunctivo_Pretérito">
    <person type="first_person">aparcare</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcares</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcare</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcáremos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcareis</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcaren</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Condicional">
    <person type="first_person">aparcaría</person>
    <person type="second_person">aparcarías</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparcaría</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparcaríamos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcaríais</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparcarían</person>
</tense>
<tense type="Imperativo">
    <person type="first_person"></person>
    <person type="second_person">aparca</person>
    <person type="third_person">aparque</person>
    <person type="first_person_plural">aparquemos</person>
    <person type="second_person_plural">aparcad</person>
    <person type="third_person_plural">aparquen</person>
</tense>
```

Parsing the key and definition into a database is trivial. It is when I get to the tenses that I am unsure what to do. My first strategy was to do as I had done xml parsing in the past - to write a class that extends DefaultHandler and use logic such as:

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("word")) {
        this.wordTag = true;
            }
}
```

and

```
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if (this.wordTag) {
        verb.setWord(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

This is not bad if there are only a couple of elements, but with elements such as  that have many different attributes using boolean flags becomes really cumbersome quickly. I feel like there has to be a better way.

I have the firefox sqlite plugin. but it doesn't seem to parse the xml correctly when I import it.

So - part one of my question is what is the best way to get this information into a sqlite database?

And part two - is using a seperate column for each verb conjugation the best way to set up the database? This approach ends up with ~50 columns, which seems excessive.

Thanks.

Comment: Since I'm on my phone, I won't waste an answer... I found the SAX parser easy to use, and my suggestion for your db would be to have a table for the unary data like definition, Infinitive, etc, and a second table for the multi-form conjugations with a column for each form, and a col to indicate the tense. Or a col for the tense and one for the form...